# Height: 100% Not Working Even Though All Parents Have Height: 100%

Tags: html, css, polymer

**Setting `height: 100%` for `<div> .ui` in the HTML below does not work even though all the parent elements have `height` set to `100%`.**

Could this be because I'm using `<core-header-panel>`? I checked its code but I don't see anything that would override the height.

Could this be due to using the `layout horizontal` attributes?

*The `layout` attributes (built on top of [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)) and `core-header-panel` are part of [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/).*

This is the HTML (simplified):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>   
  <body unresolved>
    <core-header-panel>
      <div layout horizontal class="container">
        <div class="ui"> </div>             <!-- this does not take up 100% of
                                                 the height -->
        <div flex class="items"> </div>     <!-- this has content inside it which fills 
                                                 the height, but the <div> itself doesn't -->
```

And this is my CSS (simplified):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
core-header-panel {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.ui {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}
.items {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** Using DevTools I noticed that `<core-header-panel>` does take up 100% of the height, but `<div> .container` does not. `height: 100%;` is not crossed out for `.container` in the "Styles" tab in DevTools.

**EDIT 2: INFO ON POLYMER** [Here is a link to a simple explanation of Polymer `layout` attributes](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html) and [here is a link to some information on `core header panel`.](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/layout-elements.html) There are Github links on the top right of both pages.

Comment: So `.container` **does** receive its 100% height?

Comment: Are you using devtools? Can you see what devtools thinks the height is of each element?

Comment: @misterManSam I added more info above. Since the element beside the `<div>` in question does take up 100% of the height, I assume that `.container` receives 100% height.

Comment: @ShailenTuli DevTools shows that `<core-header-panel>` does take up 100%, but `.container` does not.

Comment: @misterManSam I checked using DevTools and `.container` does not appear to receive 100% (see comment above). `height: 100%;` is not crossed out for `.container` in the "Styles" tab in DevTools.

Comment: There is not enough info to go on at the moment. Can you provide a demo of some kind? Can you compile polymer into vanilla js/HTML/CSS/whatever? I have no idea how polymer works!

Comment: @misterManSam I did includes links to Polymer and CSS Flexbox, but I will try to somehow add some information now.

Comment: @misterManSam I added links to some short explanations and code on the `layout` attributes and `core-header-panel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was actually really simple.

I had to add `fullbleed vertical layout` to `<core-header-panel>`. `fullbleed` forces it to take up the entire height of the parent. I didn't see a reason for this since I specified `height: 100%`, but it appears that it does not work without it.

I also added `fit` to `<div> .container` to make it fit the parent.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>   
  <body unresolved>
    <core-header-panel fullbleed vertical layout>  <!-- added "fullbleed vertical layout" here -->
      <div fit layout horizontal class="container">  <!-- added "fit" here -->
        <div class="ui"> </div>             
        <div flex class="items"> </div>
```